# Cycle Detection Algorithm: Is there a condition for Tortoise and Hare to enter into cycle?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, cycle-detection

Recently I attended an interview and came accross the following question which I am not able to figure out.

**Question-1:**

As per the proof which I read Tortoise moves 1 step and Hare moves 2 steps at a time. I understood this and they will meet at some point since Hare moves twice the speed of Tortoise. Can't they have any random values like 2 and 3 or 3 and 5 or 2 and 4. If so, will they ever figure out the cycle? What is the condition for choosing the Tortoise and Hare values? Can we choose any random values?

**Question-2:**

Is there any condition for Tortoise and Hare to enter into the loop?
Suppose if Tortoise and Hare have following values say 2 and 4 resp. And the linked list is like

> ```
>             3   
>           /   \
>     1 -  2     4
>           \   /
>             5
> ```

If Tortoise enters in to loop at node 3 and Hare enters loop at node 2 then they both never meet each other inside the loop. So is there a condition for Tortoise and Hare to enter the loop?

Are there any confined values that should be choosen such that they meet each other?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what _"Should the Tortoise and Hare have values only 1 and 2. Can't they have any random values like 2 and 3 or 3 and 5 or 2 and 4."_ is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Codor Updated the question, point is "Can we choose any values for Tortoise and hare if so will they satisfy the condition for entering into the loop"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RE Q1: the greatest common divisor of tortoise and hare speeds must not be a divisor (other than 1) of loop length. So e.g. if `gcd(vTortoise, vHare)=2`, it will detect loops of odd lengths, but may fail for loops of even length. Q2 relates to the cases where it fails.

RE Q2: to detect a loop when the above restriction does not hold, i.e. when loop length is evenly divisible by `M = gcd(vTortoise, vHare)`, loop will not be detected if tortoise and hare enter the loop at positions with different modulo `M` from the beginning of the loop. So in the above example, `M=2` and loop will be detected if both hare and tortoise enter at positions with equal modulo M, e.g. 0 and 2, 0 and 4, 2 and 4, 1 and 3, etc. But loop will not be detected (thus tortoise and hare will travel infinitely) if they enter the loop e.g. at positions 0 and 1, or 0 and and 3, 1 and 2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Say tortoise start at point numbered `T` and take steps S<sub>t</sub> and Hare start at `H` and take steps S<sub>h</sub>.

The necessary and sufficient condition for them to meet is

> |T - H| = k X gcd (S<sub>t</sub> , S<sub>h</sub>)

i.e. the difference in their starting position should be the multiple of `gcd` of their steps.

Answer (score 1):

The movement rates for the two must be relatively prime, in order to catch cycles of any length. I think that's a sufficient condition.

Comment: What about the second question? Is there any condition for them to enter into the loop?

Comment: Yes, this somehow makes sense, but the relative primality is unrelated to the graph, which I understood to be part of the input. Is the graph part of the input or is it fixed?

Comment: @Codor It is the fixed input. The input shown above is fixed.

Comment: Tortoise and hare is one example of Floyd's cycle detection algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection